# JS not changing element style

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with the following script:

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert('portrait');
}
```

The script above works fine but if I change it to

```
 if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert('portrait');
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display='inline';
    alert('portrait2');
}
```

it stops working after the first alert. My `popup` element looks like that:

```
<h1 id="popup" style="display:none">hi</h1>
```

Comment: Does any error appear in the console ?

Comment: So second alert doesn't appear?

Comment: It works for me :/ maybe there is an error in console that block it.

Comment: The code works as-is: [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZY32/)

Comment: Strange, I don't see any errors in my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RwF45/1/)

Make sure you have your `<script>` tag at the end of your `</body>`.

Or wrap in it a `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
 if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert('portrait');
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display='inline';
    alert('portrait2');
  }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9PNLV/)

Comment: Thanks, the onload function solved it.